# PowerShell - How to display a list of files that have been changed via replace

Tags: powershell

I need to know how to display a list of files that were exactly through the replace, at the moment it displays all files in a folder and subfolders, this output is not informative

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $environment
)

Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include "*.*" -Exclude "*.ps1", "*.yml" | foreach-object {
    $Item = $_.fullname; ( get-content $Item ) | foreach-object {
        $_ -replace "{env}", "$environment" 
    }  
    | set-content $Item
}
#-gt
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -include "*.*" -Exclude "*.ps1", "*.yml" | Where-Object { $_.LastAccessTime -gt (get-date).AddSeconds(-15) -and $_.LastWriteTime -gt (get-date).AddSeconds(-15) } | Select-Object LastWriteTime , Name
```

Response:

```
LastWriteTime       Name
-------------       ----
01.06.2021 12:16:46 test-number-1F.txt
01.06.2021 12:16:46 test-number-2F.txt
01.06.2021 12:16:46 test-number-3F.txt
01.06.2021 12:16:46 test-number-4F.txt
01.06.2021 12:16:46 text.json
```

But for example the text.json file is always empty and it should never appear in the output

PS. I am try to using the LastWriteTime because I don’t know any alternative how to accomplish this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "easy" way to see if file has been touched by modification, so we need to find a "workaround" of some sort.
BTW since you are setting content of every file regardless of the replace action taking place or not - `LastWriteTime` will always be modified.

I got some problems with `-include` and `-exclude` switches with my files, so I kinda refactored your code.

I created two lists. First consists of changed files and second is used to store content of the file (regardless if line has been changed or not). Why list and not array? Adding to array drops "old" one and creates a new one with new element in it. In case of big files this can be a performance issue.

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string] $environment
)
$modifiedFilesList = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string];
$files = Get-ChildItem -File | Where-Object {$_.Name -notlike "*.yml" -and $_.Name -notlike "*.ps1"};

foreach ($file in $files.FullName) {
    #create a new list to save content
    $newContent = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[string];

    foreach ($line in (Get-Content $file)) {
        #save line for comparison
        $original = $line; 
        $modified = $line -replace "{env}", "$environment";
        if ($original -ne $modified) {
            #line has changed (skip the case sensitive search, cause we are changing a token here. Case sensitive switch is '-cne')
            $line = $modified;
            $modifiedFilesList.Add($file); #save the file as modified
        }
        $newContent.Add($line); #add content to list that will be saved to file
    }
    $newContent | Set-Content $file; #set content of file
}

if ($modifiedFilesList.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Output "Files changed: `n$([string]::Join("`n", $modifiedFilesList))";
}
else {
    Write-Output "No files changed";
}
```